# UINavigationBar for JQuery Mobile, or other HTML solution

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile-safari

I am building a PhoneGap app that uses JQuery Mobile, and I would like the app to feel as much like a native app as possible.  What out there emulates the look and feel of a native UINavigationController best in Safari-land?

I'd much prefer to write all the silly user interface code in HTML/Javascript, rather than using verbose Objective C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the other JavaScript mobile frameworks (Sencha Touch, jQTouch, ChocolateChip-UI, AppML, etc) have built-in navigation emulating the UINavigationController in HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

jQuery Mobile does too, but it seems less like it is trying to look exactly like a UINavigationController.

eg: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/index.html

In the above demo you can see that there is a top menu bar with back buttons as you navigate through the demo.

However, if you want it to emulate the native UINavigationController more closely, you might be better off looking at one of the other frameworks I mentioned above.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good answer.  I'll leave the question open for a bit in case somebody has a way to style JQuery Mobile like iOS.

Comment: You might be able to repurpose a jQtouch theme, or at least use it as the basis for making your own Apple-like theme.